# How i upload my MEAN App (Website Application) on Digital Ocean?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, digital-ocean, mean

i have a question please some body help me to out this
How i upload my MEAN App (Website Application)  on Digital Ocean?

Answer (score 0):

You can host your MEAN stack application to degital ocean by following this steps listed on this article:
[How to Host a MEAN Stack App on Digital Ocean](https://morioh.com/p/59e6e95ed312)

#### Creating an SSH Key:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

#### Registering your Account:

Before we get started, you should have a fully functional Digital Ocean account.

Registering an account is pretty simple.

Here is a walkthrough of the registration process.

1. Adding your personal details along with your email address.
2. Verifying your account using the email sent at your provided email address in step one.
3. Adding your credit card details.

#### Creating your Droplet:

Once you have registered your account, move to the **Droplets** section at the dashboard and click the **Create Droplet** button.

when you create choose your OS and next .
We are going to use the MEAN 0.5.0 on 20.04 stack.
[image]

After that complete the droplet creation by select the **region** and **add** the **SSH key** generated before  .

Next Steps:

#### Login to your droplet:

Execute the following command to create a remote terminal session to your droplet.

```sh
$ ssh -i <path-to-your-key-file> root@<your-droplet-ip>
```

You code uploaded to the droplet now check that npm and node is installed on your droplet using:

```sh
npm version
node version
```

#### Install and configure Nginx:

```sh
apt install nginx
```

Next, configure Nginx using the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file.

```sh
server {
    listen 80;

server_name &lt;your-droplet-ip&gt;;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://&lt;your-droplet-ip&gt;:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

}
```

Restart Nginx service by executing the command  `sudo service nginx restart`

Point your browser to **http://** and you will see the sample application's welcome page again.

Specifying the IP address only without the need to add port **3000** shows Nginx was setup correctly.

In other words, web browsers forward requests to port **80** by default and since we have Nginx running on port 80 ready to forward requests to the Node application, everything works as expected.

#### Keeping your Application Alive:

PM2 is a Node process manager that allows you to run your applications as a service in the background which is restarted whenever it goes down.

##### Deploy your app:

1- cloning repository at /opt/mean

```sh
$ git clone your-repo-url "mean"
```

2- Move to the project root.

```sh
$ cd /opt/mean
```

###### Install NPM modules.

```sh
$ npm install
```

Finally, execute the following command to start your application using PM2.

```sh
$ pm2 start server.js
```

Point your browser to **http://** and you should see the application's home page.

I think that can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Great let me add details to the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Dear Rassakar but i already view this link but it can't hlep me is there other way or reference you have